# Getting product url and thumbnail in order-confirmation mail that goes to seller

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, product-images, sellers-dashboard

I have solved this issue of getting product URL and thumbnail that goes to customer mail
this is my code:

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());

$imagewidth=200;
$imageheight=200;
$imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl();
for showing product url:    <div class="product-name"><a href="<?= $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl(); ?>"> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></div>
For showing Image:<?= $image_url ?>
```

Now this have been done from customer perspective. when the same mail goes to seller changes are not reflecting to their email.

So how to make changes so that seller can see product URL & Thumbnail in his/her email to or his/her end.

Thanks

Comment: Where you are writing this code ?

Comment: for customers its already done and iam getting email as a customer having both product image & url
i have used default.html in magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order
but in order to get achieve same result what to do from seller perspective

Comment: iam using  magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order and magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/  for both default.html & items.phtml

Comment: kindly reply please?

Comment: do i have to use like
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" order=$order name="order_sms" template="magento_sales::items.phtml" area="frontend"}} <-items.phtl is for showing content so do i have to use items.phtml here or default.phtml
what to put in name field?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not a proper way. You have to go with Magento coding pattern.

**First you have to create a order email template and assign this template as order email :**

1. **Create New email template** : Goto `Admin -> Marketing -> EmailTemplates -> Click On add New Template`
2. **Load Order Template** : In Template Dropdown Select “New Order” and click Load Template. It will load Default Order email template
3. **Update Order Template** : You can set / change your template name, subject and content as you want and save it.
4. **Set Order Template** : Go To `Admin -> Stores -> Sales -> Sales Email -> “New Order Confirmation Template” and “New Order Confirmation Template for Guest”`
   Here you have to select your newly created template from dropdown for order email.

Now this template is ready for your order email. Now you have to add order content in this template. For this you have to create a block file and call that block file in template content which you created.

**To Create Order detail HTML with image and link :**

For this you have to create a module (or in existing module). In that module you have to create a model file like : `app/code/[vendor]/[module]/view/frontend/templates/[filename].phtml`.

In this file you can get the order object like : `$order = $this->getData('order');`

Now you can put all your HTML with order detail which you want to send in email.

**Call this HTML in email Template :**

Edit the order email template which you created in `Admin -> Marketing -> EmailTemplates` 
To Call this HTML inside Order email content you have to put this code inside content area of email : `{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" order=$order name="order_sms" template="[vendor]_[module]::[filename].phtml" area="frontend"}}`

Comment: well i have already done for customer perspective.so is there any alternate way to get this functionality by editing files in magento which are responsible to send email to seller.
i will try this method when i live run live site..its now testing site so i want to implement the method to display product thumbnail and product url in seller emails

Comment: Email will be the same for customer and admin both, there is no change in email template.

Comment: so why seller are getting email which doest reflect changes..only customer can see product url & images but seller cant....iam not talking about admin sir iam talking about seller..so any idea?

Comment: ok sir i have created the template but how to add product thumbnail image & product url to it?

Comment: put your same code in file `app/code/[vendor]/[module]/view/frontend/templates/[filename].phtml`. Whichever html is there in this file will go in email

Comment: sir my default file which iam using is
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email
items.phtml <-for showing front end in mail
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order
default.phtml <-- this iam using to customize email so do i have to use this in my custom template..can u plz tell how to call this template in my custom email??

Comment: this is what iam getting in my email..that template is not calling at all
default.html is template which use to render into items.phtml
iam getting nothing
see:http://prntscr.com/ecdkii

Comment: are you there sir?